# Getting balance of received 1155 in receiver contract

Tags: erc-1155, receive

I'm looking to build an airdropper that receives 1155 tokens and then runs a function to send them out to an array of addresses. However, I'm a little confused on two pieces

- How to get the balance of the received token
- How to differentiate between tokens from different contracts. If contract A and contract B both send to Contract C, how do I check Contract C's balance of A and B tokens?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general I would recommend to use a pull based approach. So if someone want to distribute tokens via your contract they will approve your contract to use their tokens and then call your contract. Your contract then will use `transferFrom` to transfer the tokens to the target address (either directly or via itself). This approach will also work with ERC20 and ERC721 tokens.

As you asked specifically for ERC1155 you can also make use the [ERC-1155 Token Receiver](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155#erc-1155-token-receiver) methods. In this methods you get the `from`, the `id` and the `value` of every transfer. Additionally to that you also can access the `msg.sender` which will correspond to the ERC-1155 token address (the contract that called the token receiver method), so in your example the addresses of contract A and contract B.